# Enable CharmBar to Our App in Windows8 Metro apps?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, charms-bar

Hi I have developed a metro app using HTML5 and JavaScript, I want to work with charm bar when am inside my app.But here default Charm-bar is showing but not enabled to my app?
                        Here actually am not following the groups concept(which was given in metro default-templates) to fill the list-views in my application and am filling my list-views with json response(own services),and how can I enable search to my list-views,I have referred Microsoft API but am not able to do searching?Can anyone help me how to enable Charm-bar to our specific app(for customized data)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The CharmBar can't be disabled in your app. If you move your mouse to one of the right corners or swipe from the right to the left on the right corner it should come up.

The only thing you can do with the CharmBar in your app is adding custom functionality to a few things like Search, Settings, Share etc. I'm not sure what you're exactly looking for, but this is an example of how to add search functionality within your app to the CharmBar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465238.aspx

Comment: You can also bring up the charms bar with <Windows key>+C

Comment: finally I got,Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The videos at http://aka.ms/jump481 might help you learn how to implement the various contracts like search and share.

Comment: Thank you,Here Am able to see my list items in charm-Bar but am unable to perform click operation for that listview-item.I need to go to details page when I click charm-bar item,what should I do?